# User-chosen URLs and their availability in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

I'm hoping to offer my users the ability to choose the address for their profile page, for example www.mydomain.com/chris_p/. The first check is obviously to ensure that no other user has already taken that address, which can easily be done with a database lookup. What I'm not sure about is how you could ensure that the address is not already in use by your Zend application.

Ideally I'd like to check against all existing routes, for example /editprofile, /join, etc. Is it possible to do a lookup on these routes by URL, to decide whether the address is available or not?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you should use an URL like "yourdomain.tld/**user**/user_name" or "/**profile**/user_name" or something like that.

Comment: This seems like better practice to me. You could use mod_rewrite with apache to still allow the user to have whatever exact url they want, and it would map on the backend to some route that you define and know is unique, "/user" or "/profile" as suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a request using Zend_Http_Client to www.mydomain.com/user_name/ and get the status code.
If status is 404, means you can use that name.